# Sort an array element closest to known element based on it's index

Tags: javascript, sorting

Let's assume an array

**Example 1 :**

```
let arr = [101,102,104,103,105]
known_element = 104;

//Output  [104,102,103,101,105]
```

**Example 2 :**

```
let arr = [4,6,3,5,1,9,2,7,8]
known_element = 9;

//Output  [9,1,2,5,7,3,8,6,4]
```

Sort the above array in such a way,

- known_element should be always at 0th element
- second,third.. element should be closest to known_element by **it's index not by value**

Note: sorting should be done based on index closest to known_element.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service where you can just dump your homework questions.

Comment: @Cerbrus I tried and searched for solution too. it's easy to sort the closest element by value. but didn't found any solution to sort based on closest index.
Please help if you know the solution. Thank you !

Comment: @Cerbrus 
https://playcode.io/951828/

Comment: Add that code in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes sense to find location of known number first

```
var pos = arr.indexOf(known_element);
```

Then we are going to loop up and down, getting numbers from closest to farthest. Let's see to which side is longer length.

```
var length = Math.max(pos, arr.length - pos + 1)
```

Ok, our result array is ready (to be filled), lets loop

```
var result = [known_element];
for (var i = 1; i < length; i++) {
  if (pos- i >= 0) {
    result.push(arr[pos - i])
  }
  if (pos + i < arr.length) {
    result.push(arr[pos + i]);
  }
}
```

I think that's it!

Test and let me know which edge case I forgot.

Comment: Thanks for answering!

https://playcode.io/951828/ first element getting lost.

Comment: Thanks, then that's the edge case. Fix it by making the loop last one more item. (length should be bigger by 1)